# Add count to queryset

Tags: django, django-models

I have a two models.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

   @property
   def element_count()
      return Element.objects.filter(name=self.name).count()


class Element(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

I want to have the count of every Element what has connected to this category.
This function works fine with templates and views but is there some way to get directly in the queryset?

If do like this `Category.objects.all()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> from django.db.models import Count
>>> q = Category.objects.all().annotate(element_count = Count('element'))

>>> print q[0].element_count
223
```

Doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: Thanks. It looks very well.

Comment: Do you know how I can add it as a virtual field?

Comment: What do you mean by a virtual field? `element_count` will be an alias in the executed SQL query.

Comment: Because I want to serialize the data and it only takes fields like with normal django serializer

Comment: Ok I get it. `json = simplejson.dumps(list(q.values()))`. It should work. :)

Comment: Thanks for help. I will see if I can use it but nice to know.. :)